# may be complete or completed

Tags: tense

I wonder if in this sentence the word **completed** can be used instead of **complete**:

> ... used to estimate when the operation may be complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. When it means "finished, all done", referring to some operation or activity, these two are very often interchangeable.

But when "complete" means "has all its parts, is not missing anything", it cannot be replaced by "completed".